# Can't access property from outside function PHP?

Tags: php, properties

I am trying to access a property outside of a function in PHP, but it is not working?

```
<?php
class Bootstrap {
private $_url = null;

public function init() {
    $this->_loadController();
}

public function getUrl() {
    $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $this->_url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
}

public function _loadController() {
    echo $this->_url[0];
}
}
```

If I echo **$this->_url[0]** in the method **getUrl** and then call it from my index page, I get the URL. While if I call it from the **_loadController** method, I just get a blank page. I did **var_dump($this->_url)** and got NULL.
My code in my index page is follows

```
<?php
include 'bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
$app = $bootstrap->init();
?>
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: in your code, you did not call `getUrl()`. Call this method in `init`  or before calling init method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem because, you did not call `getUrl()`, but in this method you set value`into $_url`. Change you code to this:

```
    class Bootstrap {
        private $_url = null;

        public function init() {
            $this->_loadController();
        }

        public function getUrl() {
            $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
            $this->_url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
        }

        public function _loadController() {
            $this-> getUrl();    // here you call getUrl()
            echo $this->_url[0];
        }
    }
```

Or, you can use   [magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) mathod to set the url into, here:

```
 class Bootstrap {
        private $_url = null;

        public function init() {
            $this->_loadController();
        }

        public function __construct() {
            $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
            $this->_url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
        }

        public function _loadController() {
            echo $this->_url[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sergio. So if I want to access a property, I have to call the function first?

Comment: Wow you saved me a ton of work and head scratching. Thanks @sergio

Comment: I did I just had to wait 10 minutes. @lila

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev, thanks for comment.sometimes people just forgot to do it)